# GitLab CI test differences between master and branch with Node

Tags: node.js, git, continuous-integration

Currently I am trying to test the differences between master and a branch on GitLab CI.

```
var branch = require('git-branch'),
    gitDiffTree = require('git-diff-tree'),
    path = require('path');

var branch = process.env.CI_BUILD_REF_NAME || branch.sync();
var repoPath = path.resolve(process.env.REPO || (__dirname + '/../.git'));

{
  repoPath: repoPath,
  gitDiffTreeOptions: {
    rev: 'master..' + branch
  }
}
```

Here is the important bits of code that I'm using. This works great locally, but when ran on GitLab CI it says `fatal: bad revision 'master.. branch'` both times the `branch` variable was populated with the same value. Any advice how to get this to work? It previously used to do `rev: HEAD` which didn't work great because it only tested the most recent commit in the branch not all of them together.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (`bad revision 'master'` when running `git diff master -- .` and similar commands), and got it working as follows:

1. run `git fetch origin master` (from the pipeline)
2. when referring to the master branch, use `origin/master` rather than `master`

I suppose the way gitlab fetches the repository contents does not cause `master` to be a valid branch name locally. I'm not familiar enough with the guts of git to pinpoint exactly why.